# Generating xtext back-end code based on configurable file (File having rules)

Tags: xtext

I wanted to know, is it possible to generate back-end code in xtext by reading file where all keywords and it fields were defined.

In the current xtext flow, we first create rules.xtext file and then use MWE workflow for generating the back-end code.

Can this be configurable through file? Means I will define all rules in a file and xtext framework will use this file and generate code.

For an instance, assume we have 2 keywords ADD and SUB, latter we wanted to add some more keywords (say MUL, DID etc.) and remove some of the existing ones.

My use case here is:

We are planning create initial xtext based setup (e.g initial keywords, editor, assist etc.). Any addition of new keywords or modification of the existing keywords should be done at runtime by reading file (Basically we wanted to avoid changing rules.xtext file and then re-generating back-end code)

Is it possible?

Comment: i am not sure what the target for this change is but if it really is just about changing existing keyword and not add new ones or delete ones or introduce new ones this sounds like a "extenal lexer" manually written by you that does the lexing (tokenization) of the files by your inputs. otherwise if you really want to change the grammar and create a new one, call the workflow etc i dont know what your specific question is: yes you can do that but you have to build the infrastructure yourself. => can you elaborate more on your actual usecase

Comment: I am creating a language for  assembler instructions. At present we have around 50 instructions (e.g. Machine instructions, Macros etc) but it may grow up to 1K. As I don't have experience on assembler level programming, so we had a thought that, can it be possible to configure it based on some file. So initially we will provide skeleton say for these 50 instructions and letter assembler programmer will take care of adding new instructions without any change in plugin. These newly added instructions should be available in editor (CTRL+SPACE) when they start writing assembler code.

Comment: But are the instructions keywords then and not references to a instruction concept written in the dsl as well or a second dsl

Comment: Yes instructions are keywords here. e.g we have an instruction "BEGIN" which takes variable number of arguments separated by comas and first field is mandatory which is NAME. I have rule defined for this in .xtext file as follows             tag=('BEGIN') name=MYSTRING (',' params+=MYSTRING)* where MYSTRING is Datatype or Terminal rule

Comment: no i mean it this way:  tag=[Tag] name=MYSTRING (',' params+=MYSTRING)*

Comment: yes (tag=[Tag] name=MYSTRING (',' params+=MYSTRING)*)

Comment: Then you should try that